# Azure YAML Pipeline ServiceNow Connector Can't Access Variable Values

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, servicenow

I have an Azure YAML Pipeline that is setting variables in a step to use in later steps.  For example, setting a timestamp to a variable and passing later into the ServiceNow Change Management connector for the "planned start date" field.  The problem is, the planned start date field does not seem to accept any syntax for the pipeline's variables.  The pipeline fails no matter what I try.  The ServiceNow Change Management connector exists in an environment check in the pipeline's step.

Here's my example YAML:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - development
  paths:
    include:
    - /migrations

stages:
- stage: SetVariablesStage
  jobs:
  - job: SetVariableJob
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        $dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        $scheduledDateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        $plannedStartDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60).ToString($dateTimeFormat)
        $plannedEndDateTime = (Get-Date).ToString($dateTimeFormat)
        $scheduledStartDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60).ToString($scheduledDateTimeFormat)
        $scheduledEndDateTime = (Get-Date).ToString($scheduledDateTimeFormat)
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=plannedStartDateTime;isOutput=true]$plannedStartDateTime"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=plannedEndDateTime;isOutput=true]$plannedEndDateTime"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=scheduledStartDateTime;isOutput=true]$scheduledStartDateTime"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=scheduledEndDateTime;isOutput=true]$scheduledEndDateTime"
        echo "plannedStartDateTime: $plannedStartDateTime"
        echo "plannedEndDateTime: $plannedEndDateTime"
        echo "scheduledStartDateTime: $scheduledStartDateTime"
        echo "scheduledEndDateTime: $scheduledEndDateTime"
      displayName: 'Set Custom Variables'
      name: SetVariableStep
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
- stage: 'dev_stage'
  dependsOn: SetVariablesStage
  variables:
    - group: TestPipeline-Variables_Dev
    - name: env
      value: "dev"
  jobs:      
  - deployment: DeployToDevelopment
    variables:
      plannedStartDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.plannedStartDateTime'] ]
      plannedEndDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.plannedEndDateTime'] ]
      scheduledStartDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.scheduledStartDateTime'] ]
      scheduledEndDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.scheduledEndDateTime'] ]
    displayName: 'Deploying to Development'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 
      name: 'Development'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:          
          - checkout: self
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            displayName: 'Use Python 3.8.x'
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.8.x'
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                <redacted: Deployment script>

  - job: update_ServiceNow
    dependsOn: DeployToDevelopment
    variables:
      plannedStartDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.plannedStartDateTime'] ]
      plannedEndDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.plannedEndDateTime'] ]
      scheduledStartDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.scheduledStartDateTime'] ]
      scheduledEndDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.scheduledEndDateTime'] ]
    steps:
    - task: UpdateServiceNowChangeRequest@2
      inputs:
        ServiceNowConnection: 'ServiceNow_Sandbox'
        NewStatus: '6'
        otherParameters: '{  "u_work_notes": "$(Build.BuildNumber) $(plannedStartDateTime) $(plannedEndDateTime)", "u_scheduled_start": "$(scheduledStartDateTime)", "u_scheduled_end": "$(scheduledEndDateTime)"  }'
pool: server
```

Example ServiceNow connection configuration:

[image: ServiceNow Configuration]

For the Control Options: Linked Variable Group, I have it connected to the correct Variable group.

When I run the pipeline, the environment check fails.  It is related to the Planned Start Date field because if I hard code a value the pipeline works.  If I remove the value it works, but later fails due to a business rule in our ServiceNow on the field.

How do I use a variable in the field so I don't have to hard code it? The last step in the pipeline that updates servicenow works correctly. I am able to set the "otherParameters" correctly with the pipeline variables. Just not in the Environment Check ServiceNow connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, the planned start date field does not seem to accept any syntax for the pipeline's variables.

The `ServiceNow Change Management` in environment approval `cannot` directly invoke the variables which created in previous stage/job.

You can try to output the variable value to **validate**. For example, output in `Approvals`:

[image]

To use the variable value, as an alternative, you can put the target value to `variable group`, and link to this group in `ServiceNow Change Management`, then you can use the variable inside.

[image]

[image]

I don't have servicenow account, so i checked with `rest api approval` as an example.

I updated the variable group variable value in powershell task. Make sure the `{project} build service(org)` account has administrator role on the Variable group security so that it can update the variable value.

[image]

```
stages:
- stage: SetVariablesStage
  jobs:
  - job: SetVariableJob
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        $dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        $scheduledDateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        $plannedStartDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60).ToString($dateTimeFormat)
        $plannedEndDateTime = (Get-Date).ToString($dateTimeFormat)
        $scheduledStartDateTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60).ToString($scheduledDateTimeFormat)
        $scheduledEndDateTime = (Get-Date).ToString($scheduledDateTimeFormat)
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=plannedStartDateTime;isOutput=true]$plannedStartDateTime"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=plannedEndDateTime;isOutput=true]$plannedEndDateTime"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=scheduledStartDateTime;isOutput=true]$scheduledStartDateTime"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=scheduledEndDateTime;isOutput=true]$scheduledEndDateTime"
        echo "plannedStartDateTime: $plannedStartDateTime"
        echo "plannedEndDateTime: $plannedEndDateTime"
        echo "scheduledStartDateTime: $scheduledStartDateTime"
        echo "scheduledEndDateTime: $scheduledEndDateTime"
      displayName: 'Set Custom Variables'
      name: SetVariableStep
  
    - powershell: |
        $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/27?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
        Write-Host $url
        $json = '{"id":27,"type":"Vsts","name":"TestPipeline-Variables_Dev","variables":{"plannedStartDateTimeVG":{"isSecret":false,"value":"$(SetVariableStep.plannedStartDateTime)"}, "plannedEndDateTimeVG":{"isSecret":false,"value":"$(SetVariableStep.plannedEndDateTime)"}}}'
        $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{
            Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
        }
        Write-Host "New Variable Value:" $pipeline.variables.plannedStartDateTimeVG.value
        Write-Host "New Variable Value:" $pipeline.variables.plannedEndDateTimeVG.value
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

- stage: 'dev_stage'
  dependsOn: SetVariablesStage
  variables:
    - group: TestPipeline-Variables_Dev
    - name: env
      value: "dev"
  jobs:      
  - deployment: DeployToDevelopment
    variables:
      plannedStartDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.plannedStartDateTime'] ]
      plannedEndDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.plannedEndDateTime'] ]
      scheduledStartDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.scheduledStartDateTime'] ]
      scheduledEndDateTime: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariablesStage.SetVariableJob.outputs['SetVariableStep.scheduledEndDateTime'] ]
    displayName: 'Deploying to Development'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 
      name: 'Development'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:          
          - checkout: self
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            displayName: 'Use Python 3.8.x'
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.8.x'
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo 1 $(plannedStartDateTime)
                echo 2 $(plannedEndDateTime)
                echo 3 $(scheduledStartDateTime)
                echo 4 $(scheduledEndDateTime)
```

I simply invoked the variable from Variable group in the url:

[image]

Confirm the variable is correctly get in rest api url when pipeline started.
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I tried as well.  I used a powershell script to update my variable in my variable group/library, then tried to use that value in the Planned Start Date field in the connector. It still generates an error for the pipeline and doesn't seem to be able to access the variable group values. I will test once more though in case I missed something.

Comment: Using Powershell to update the variable and then access it through the service now connector worked. I tried this many times the day before but must have had a typo in how I was using the variable because I was able to get the variable in the group updated but not get the value.  Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction, will mark as the answer!

Comment: Glad to know it helps! Cheers!

Comment: One final follow up. When calling the REST API for distributedtask/variablegroups it seems this overwrites the entire variable group. So you need to include all variables in the group or they get removed. Is there a way to update specific variables in the group through a different API call? My other option is to use "az pipelines variable-group variable update" which I can use to individually update variables in the variable group.

Comment: Yes, you’re correct. The rest api will overwrite the entire variable group, not just the specific variable you’re trying to update. You can retrieve the entire variable group, update the specific variable value, and then update the entire variable group with the new set of variables. But better way is to use the Azure CLI `az pipelines variable-group variable update`. Yaml sample: - bash: |
    az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 21 --name Var1 --value Value2
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)